# Throwing an error when initializing an object in c++

Tags: data-structures

Let's say that when initializing a pet class, I wanted to exclude or disallow dogs or cats as species. What would be the proper way to throw an invalid_argument exception?

```
using std::string;
#include <stdexcept>
using std:: invalid_argument;
struct Pet {
  const string name;
  long age = 0;
  const string species;
  Pet() : name("Dan"), age(0), species("alligator"){}
  Pet(const string & the_name, const string & the_species): name(the_name),
  species(the_species), age(0) {};
};
```

Comment: Your question is a programming question, and I think you should ask it on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Pet(const string & the_name, const string & the_species): name(the_name), species(the_species), age(0)
  {

     if (species == "cats" || species == "dogs")
        throw std::invalid_argument( "received negative value" );
  }
```

Comment: Just to remind you, the strict programming questions are off-topic here. If this gets closed or migrated to SO, I think that some comment to the code or textual info would also be required to count it as the answer.